# Monitor a computer DVI output inside windows using DVI Input Card

Tags: display, dvi, input, local, screen-sharing

I have a nice Mac Mini G4 and i wanted to start building a server with it. I plugged it up and everything but it seems like my monitor DVI interface has issues and cannot output the image properly. I don't really feel like changing the monitor for this since it's still damn sharp with HDMI.

I was wondering if it was possible to send the Mac DVI signal into my windows computer using a DVI Input card (http://www.epiphan.com/solutions_new/other/how-to-make-a-choice-among-dvi-capture-cards/) and read that input inside a window (also, what software offers this?). I would find a way to share my computer input most probably by using synergy (since i can't connect a device to two computers) and that way i could manage my server without switching input on my monitor. I know some network based app exist like VNC and TeamViewer but i would rather directly send the video input straight to the computer.

That way i would save a lot of local bandwidth!

Thanks!

I run OSX Server 10.4.11 and also Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: That feels seriously like a overcomplicated solution to the problem - DVI -> HDMI converters exist and passive ones (which might be good enough) cost a few dollars.

Comment: I could run both one inside the other, that would defenetly be better, no?